# Convert string command of Gremlin to executable

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

I have created a long Gremlin chained command as a string. What is the best way to execute it in NodeJS or Python?

```java
g.addV("person").
  property(id, 1).
  property("name", "marko").
  property("age", 29).as("1").
  addV("person").
  property(id, 2).
  property("name", "vadas").
  property("age", 27).as("2").
  addV("software").
  property(id, 3).
  property("name", "lop").
  property("lang", "java").as("3").
  addV("person").
  property(id, 4).
  property("name", "josh").
  property("age", 32).as("4").
  addV("software").
  property(id, 5).
  property("name", "ripple").
  property("lang", "java").as("5").
  addV("person").
  property(id, 6).
  property("name", "peter").
  property("age", 35).as("6").
  addE("created").from("1").to("3").
  property(id, 9).
  property("weight", 0.4).
  addE("knows").from("1").to("2").
  property(id, 7).
  property("weight", 0.5).
  addE("knows").from("1").to("4").
  property(id, 8).
  property("weight", 1.0).
  addE("created").from("3").to("4").
  property(id, 11).
  property("weight", 0.4).
  addE("created").from("3").to("6").
  property(id, 12).
  property("weight", 0.2).
  addE("created").from("4").to("5").
  property(id, 10).
  property("weight", 1.0)
```

The command given above was executed on the Gremlin console and was successful, but I need to know how to achieve this in program of node or Python using TinkerPop drive.

Answer (score 2):

Start with Gremlin Language Variants (GLV) and then head over to Gremlin-python.

The docs should be good enough for you to solve this yourself.

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/gremlin-language-variants/#using-python-and-gremlin-server

Answer (score 1):

```py
from gremlin_python.driver import client

client = client.Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')

client.submit("your query")
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying this code to execute the query from the lambda function and from my local as well machine, but getting a timeout error. instead of it, if using DriveRemoteConnection of gremlin_python, it working fine, but using this was, not getting the solution to execute dynamic query string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to use with any Gremlin driver, I used Python and used
`client.submit("you query")`.
And it worked.